How can I convert responses from a Google Form into a series of rows for a selected response
I have a Google Form that is linked to a Google Sheet.
The form asks users for their username, and then a series of checkbox-style questions for a few games. It's not required that each user has an answer for each game, so it's possible for a question to have nothing selected.
My goal is to have a sheet that takes a single user's form response:



Timestamp
Username
Elden Ring
Fallout 4
Skyrim




4/26/2024 16:17:33
firstUser
Beat Game, Would Recommend
Beat Game




and formats it into an easier to read sheet (the X and _ are meant to indicate checkboxes):



firstUser (dropdown)
Beat Game
Would Recommend




Elden Ring
X
X


Fallout 4
X
_


Skyrim
_
_



I intend to have more games at some point, so I'd prefer not to hardcode the row/column values if I can help it. I've sort of managed to get the responses to line up into the correct row, but then I still need to split up the values into the correct column and convert them to checkboxes. I'd also like to avoid making custom scripts , unless you think it's really recommended for this.
I'm currently on the following set of functions:
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN("||", QUERY(INDIRECT("FormResponses!B2:"&ADDRESS(ROWS(FormResponses!B2:B), COLUMNS(FormResponses!B2:2), 4)), "SELECT * WHERE Col1 = '"&$A1&"'")), $A1&"\|\|(.*)"),"||"))

I'm not well versed in Sheets, and I'm stuck at the next steps here, or if I'm even on the right track (maybe there's some other function that I'm overlooking that would make this a lot easier?). Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Some notes:

The INDIRECT is being used so I don't have to worry about additional rows/columns, since I effectively want to look at everything.
Then I QUERY for the username selected in the dropdown in A1.
JOIN the values into a single row and REGEXEXTRACT everything except for the username
SPLIT and TRANSPOSE the results to match the rows that I separate transposed from the columns in the form response sheet.

Thanks in advance.

You can do a 2D lookup with INDEX-XMATCH-XMATCH to retrieve the responses of a particular user for a particular game and then use REGEXMATCH to check which options have been selected.
This formula in cell B2 would auto fill all the checkboxes in the range B2:C:
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAP(A2:A,LAMBDA(game,
   IFNA(REGEXMATCH(
      INDEX(FormResponses!A:ZZZ,XMATCH(A1,FormResponses!B:B),XMATCH(game,FormResponses!1:1)),
      B1:C1)))))

